# Using Same Macro on Different Worksheet Without Changing Sub Name

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a very large WorkBook, utilizing the same WorkSheet format several times. I have created the WorkSheet and then I just duplicate it over and over. I will have more than 20 WorkSheets. Each WorkSheet requires a minimum of 50 or more macros performing different routines on each WorkSheet. The example below is used in the same cell for every WorkSheet (F19). Is it possible to reuse the macros without relabeling each of them.

```
Sub BI_Office_19_F()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("AC19").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("AD19").Value = 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("AE19").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("AF19").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("AG19").Value = ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you can! Try it! That's called good practice to use the same piece of code several times, intead of copying it again and again.

Comment: I'm having to change the "Sub" name for every macro - copying/paste. I was wondering if there was a simpler approach.

Comment: Sorry, on which level this macro is placed: module of worksheet or module?

Comment: I have them in Modules.

Comment: So, leave one instance of "BI_Office" procedure and remove all other instances of the same macro. Then use "Find and Replace" dialog window to replace "dd_F", where a "dd" refers to two digits.

Comment: Your posted macro runs on the ActiveSheet, so it's not specific to any single worksheet? It's not clear exactly what the problem is. Why is the *name* of the Sub significant?

Comment: That is what I have been doing. I thought there maybe a simpler way.

Comment: How are the macros being triggered/called? Are they involved with worksheet events, button triggers, ...? How are they being used?

Comment: Pass the worksheet as an argument: `Sub BI_Office_19_F(sh As Worksheet)` and then use that object instead of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Tim, You are correct - not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: Are you calling these codes from a `Worksheet_Change` event, in this case, if cell `F19` changes? If so, since you have 20 worksheets, it would be better to use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event and pass `sh` or `Target` to each of these procedures, similarly as suggested by braX.

Comment: You wrote _"The example below is used in the same cell for every WorkSheet **(F19)**"_. May I know what did you mean for "F19" ? Your `Sub BI_Office_19_F()` is meant to be run on the active sheet only. Did you mean that you want that `Sub BI_Office_19_F()` can be run for ALL sheets existed in the workbook? ---> you run this sub once only, then (for example) cell AC19 value is blank and cell AD19 value is 1 in ALL sheets ? Please CMIIW.